# Check if PowerShell window support user interaction

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm executing a PowerShell script in C# using the "PowerShellInstance" class but I'm having an issue with the commandlet "`Clear-Host`". I get some errors related to the fact that the host program or the command type does not support user interaction.

However, it must be possible to execute this script directly via PowerShell (without using C#), therefore, I want the "`Clear-Host`" command to execute only if the script has been triggered from within a PowerShell windows and not when it's triggered from the C# code.

So far, the only way I found is to wrap it in a "`Try { } Catch { }`" block but I'm wondering if there is a better solution... Something like "`if ($host.IsOk) { }`".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, if I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
if($host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle -match "PowerShell")

{

Clear-Host

}

else

{

"The script was executed from C#"

}
```

Comment: Looks like it, yes, but is it reliable? I mean, isn't there any way to launch the script in a Powershell window without the title containing "PowerShell" ? If there isn't, I guess your answer is what I'm looking for :-)

Comment: Ok, do you want to launch a PowerShell script from within another PowerShell session like this:
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -file Script.ps1"
or launch an entirely new PowerShell script in a PowerShell window like this:
Powershell.exe -windowstyle normal -executionpolicy remotesigned -file Script.ps1
Perhaps you could share your code so that I know where we stand :)